# converting html table to excel shows error on windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I want to convert html table to excel.it is working fine on `Linux` for `Libre office writer` but on windows it gives an error.

see error in attached screenshot

[image]

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.table2excel.js"></script>

<button id="b1">Export to excel</button>
<script>
  $("#b1").click(function() {
    //alert('click..');
    $("#excel").table2excel({
      // #excel is table id
      exclude: ".noExl",
      name: "Worksheet Name",
      filename: "SomeFile" //do not include extension
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

check for the OS with

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1){
     //It is Windows
} else if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1){
     //It is Linux
} else if((navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1){
     //It is Mac
}
```

and provide an appropriate extension in case of windows, since in linux extension do not have that role.

Comment: before the button click function, format your filename to any variable using the above code and use it instead of string.